# Alter icon size on hover w/o affecting other icons

Tags: css

I am altering my font awesome icons on hover to make them bigger.  The problem I am running into is that by making 1 icon bigger it moves the other icons next to it around.  I.E. the icons get moved over and down.

I have created this base fiddle to show the problem.  I have messed with padding and margin to try and create space needed around each icon such that the space is big enough that the other icons don't move.  I am a CSS rookie for sure so please go easy ;)

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/newmanw/MUHVD/

markup:

```
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
 <body>
    <div>
        <span>
            <i class="icon icon-warning-sign"></i>
            <i class="icon icon-ok"></i>
            <i class="icon icon-flag"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
  </body>
```

css

```
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css');

.icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work out for you?

```
.icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
 }
 .icon{
   float:left;
   width:30px;   
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MUHVD/1/

Comment: if you want it to expand from the center, use css:line-height:20px; for the icon class.

Comment: that works really well.  I have one more thing :(  I would like to add some text to the right of the icons, then add one more icon.  See updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/newmanw/MUHVD/  Any way that I can get the comments icon push to the right of the text.  Text is dynamic so it might be different sizes meaning the push right need to push right the correct amount.

Comment: nm, got it.  Just needed to float text left as well, then float another icon.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, this cannot be done. If you make the bottom brick of a wall bigger, all the other bricks get pushed around.

You can do this using some javascript that forces the icons into `absolute` positions, keeping them all still while one resizes.

You could also give the icons enough "padding" (not necessarily `padding`) to keep the positions straight when things resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/MUHVD/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `vertical-align` property on the icons to be `text-top`, it will keep their position the same vertically, but will still have to move them horizontally

```
.icon {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MUHVD/6/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float: left;` to `.icon` and specify the width what font-size grow after mouse over on that for eg. here you wanted to grow to 28px so you need to specify `width: 28px;` to your `.icon`.